# Issue binding style of selected item with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have the following custom element:

```
export class FilterBlockCustomElement {
   @bindable selectedfilters = [];
   @bindable filtergroup;

   //Add or remove item from selectedfilters list
   selectItem(item) {
      var location = this.selectedfilters.indexOf(item.name);
      if(location > -1)
         this.selectedfilters.splice(location);
      else
         this.selectedfilters.push(item.name);
   }
}
```

and its associated View:

```
<template>
    <div style="color: hsl(200,50%,50%); font-size: 1.2em">
        ${filtergroup.key}
    </div>

    <div click.trigger="selectItem(item)" repeat.for="item of filtergroup.data">
        <div>${item.name}</div><div>${item.count}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

What I want to happen is that anytime an item is added to the selectedfilters list, it will be highlited -- when it is removed, the highlighting will disappear.  (I realize that if I just add a property to the item (i.e. item.selected = true) this would probably work, but I'm trying to avoid that for various reasons.)

I added this to my View and VM trying to make this work:

```
<div repeat.for="item of filters" style.bind="getColor(item)">...</div>

//In VM
getColor(item){
    return {background-color: this.selectedfilters.indexOf(item.name) > -1 ? "red" : undefined}
}
```

This works on the initial page load but doesn't update the view as items are added and removed from the list.

Is it possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

Thanks to this site: https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/ I was able to find something called the signaler.  My final code looks like this:

**VM**

```js
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources' //ADDED
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework' //ADDED

@inject(BindingSignaler) //NEW
export class FilterBlockCustomElement{
    @bindable selectedfilters = [];
    @bindable filtergroup;
    signaler;  //NEW

    constructor(signaler){       //ADDED
        this.signaler = signaler
    }

    selectItem(item){
        var location = this.selectedfilters.indexOf(item.name) ;
        if(location > -1)
            this.selectedfilters.splice(location);
        else
            this.selectedfilters.push(item.name);

        this.signaler.signal('test') //ADDED
    }

    getColor(item){
        var css = {'background-color': this.selectedfilters.indexOf(item.name) > -1 ? "blue" : undefined};
        return css;
    }
}
```

**View** - Notice the style binding

```html
<template>
    <div style="color: hsl(200,50%,50%); font-size: 1.2em">
        ${filtergroup.key}
    </div>

    <div style.bind="getColor(item) & signal: 'test'" click.trigger="selectItem(item)" repeat.for="item of filtergroup.data">
        <div>${item.name}</div><div>${item.count}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Also, please use the css custom attribute instead of style. IE/Edge don't work correctly when using the style attribute, so w created the css attribute to make style binding work in all browsers.

Comment: @AshleyGrant - thanks for the heads up on that.  I had noticed a few code samples both ways in different posts and wasn't sure what the difference was.

Comment: Yeah, it is because IE/Edge looks at the style attribute and only takes it if the value is valid css. There is no workaround, so we had to create one.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind a function it will be execute the first time, but if you change its params value aurelia will not detect that.

Try this:

```
<div repeat.for="item of filters" style.bind="itemStyle[$index]">...</div>

//In VM
private itemStyle = new Array();

//Called automatically when filters property change
filtersChanged(){
    this.itemStyle = new Array();
    this.filters.forEach((item, idx) => {
        this.itemStyle[idx] = {background-color: this.selectedfilters.indexOf(item.name) -1 ? "red" : undefined}
    }) 
}
```